# Optimize query selecting elements from 3 tables mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join

The database is as follows:

```
Classes       Challenges         Class Challenges
id             id                  id
               title               class_id
                                   challenge_id
```

In order to get all the challenges of a specific class I use the following

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT class_challenges.challenge_id, 
    challenges.title
FROM class_challenges 
LEFT JOIN challenges 
    ON class_challenges.challenge_id = challenges.id
WHERE class_challenges.class_id = :class_id
ORDER BY challenge_id
```

How can I do the same for all the challenges that do not belong to a specific class?
So far I use:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT challenges.id,
    challenges.title 
FROM 
    challenges,
    class_challenges
WHERE challenges.id NOT IN(
                            SELECT 
                                DISTINCT class_challenges.challenge_id
                            FROM class_challenges
                            LEFT JOIN challenges 
                                ON class_challenges.challenge_id = challenges.id
                            WHERE class_challenges.class_id = :class_id
                            ORDER BY challenge_id
                        );
```

which I think can be written better. (maybe using a double join?)

So, how can this be optimized (if it can?)

Comment: what do you mean by do not belong to a specific class?

Comment: suppose we have a challenge with id = 1 and a class with class.id = 5. then challenge does not belong in class if in class_challenges there isn't any line with class_id = 5 and challenge_id = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your expected results it's a bit vague for me to answer, but anyway here is a code to try out. Call me *visual* ;) Please comment after you have tried out the query.

The code list down **'challenges for each class'**. You may use a `variable` to filter out the data for a specific `class id`.

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4b07/1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, 
group_concat(b.challenge_id) as challengeIs,
group_concat(c.title) as Titles
FROM Classes a
LEFT JOIN 
class_challenges b
ON a.id = b.class_id
LEFT JOIN challenges c
ON b.challenge_id = c.id
group by a.id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Results:

```
ID      CHALLENGEIS     TITLES
100     11,15       a,c
200     15          b
300     11,15       a,c
400     (null)      (null)
500     15          b
```

**Challenges that do not belong to a specific class**

*Just noticed that I have missed out to add this portion of the query.*

Query:

-- challenge that doesn't belong to a class

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id,
c.title, group_concat(a.id) as class
FROM challenges c
LEFT JOIN 
class_challenges b
ON b.challenge_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Classes a
ON a.id = b.class_id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING class is null
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Results:

```
ID  TITLE   CLASS
18  c   (null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.title,
    t.CCID
FROM
(
    SELECT      
        challenges.id,
        challenges.title,
        class_challenges.id as CCID                 
    FROM 
        challenges
    LEFT JOIN class_challenges 
        ON class_challenges.challenge_id = challenges.id
) as t  
WHERE t.CCID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using an anti-join:

```
SELECT challenges.id, challenges.title
FROM challenges
LEFT JOIN class_challenges ON class_challenges.challenge_id = challenges.id
    AND class_challenges.class_id = :class_id
WHERE class_challenges.id IS NULL
```